# how to scrollLeft overflow element without cut the child element with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, carousel

I'm making a simple carousel with `scrollLeft`, when I press the next button it will scroll based on `clientWidth` but the child element or card element on the left side is cut off,
so I want to make it without cutting the child element or card element

for example on the right side of the container element, the child elements cards 5 & 6 have been cut off (it's okay)
so when I press the next button, cards 5 & 6 will be shifted to the left side by being cut off but I don't want it by being cut off,

1. [initial view.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnQLx.jpg)
2. [cut off elements example.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llPG0.jpg)
3. [without cut off elements example.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtFt6.jpg)

here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/xhq1yok8/